# create unique hash per browser and page

Tags: c#, asp.net, hash, httprequest

I am creating a web application in c#.

I want to create a unique identifier for the current user on to be used on the current page. This idenitfier is just for this page and this users session. So it will vary per user, browser etc. I have an id for the user that I can use but also want to use a unique identifier for the browser eg session id. So I will create a hash based on user id, ip address, page identifier and browser identifier.

Is there a value from the user httprequest object that I could include in the generation of the hash?

Comment: why don't you use the current cookie?

Comment: Did you considered about just simply generating a GUID and mapping that to user id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`REMOTE_ADDR` will give you the IP
`HTTP_USER_AGENT` will give you the browser
`SCRIPT_NAME` will give you the current script running (page)

Just access those values using the `Request.ServerVariables` collection

Comment: Thanks but all of these can be replicated in another browser window. I need a unique value based upon the browser window.

Comment: The request obj doesn't have any unique identifier for the window/tab. You might be able to get some handle on this with JavaScript using window.name